# SystemJS import "base script" from directory, like in Python

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

Is it possible to import a "base script" from a module-like directory with [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), like a Python's `__init__.py`?

Example:

### Directory structure

```
app/
  module1/
    __init__.js       // or module1.js
    module1.weeble.js
    module1.thingy.js
  module2/
    __init__.js       // or module2.js
    module2.weeble.js
    module2.thingy.js
  bootstrap.js
```

### module1/__init__.js

```
import Weeble from "./module1.weeble"
import Thingy from "./module1.thingy"

class Module1 {
  constructor() {
    this.weeble = new Weeble();
    this.thingy = new Thingy();
  }
}

export default Module1
```

### bootstrap.js

Import directory to import the base script (`__init__.js` or `module1.js`) or something:

```
import Module1 from "./module1"
import Module2 from "./module2"

let module1 = new Module1();
let module2 = new Module2();

// INSTEAD OF
// import Module1 from "./module1/__init__"
// OR
// import Module1 from "./module1/module1"
```

Is this possible? Python imports a directory as a module if `__init__.py` is present in that directory

```python
# so one doesn't have to type
from module/__init__.py import module_part

# but only
from module import module_part

# or to import the entire module 
import module
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup it's possible. Use a `index.js` file for that:

**module1/index.js**

Then you can `import "./module1";`

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript itself isn't a module-based language language *(not yet)*. In order to do this you will need to include another library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I am using such a plugin: [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). It's in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I read very bad. I don`t use SystemJS but Its similary to requirejs. Then I think that is possible.