# How can I require a directory in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I know I can require a file in ES6 like this:

`require('./config/auth');`

When I try to do this

`require('./config/');`

I get: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './config'`. Why does this happen? How can I require a directory?

Comment: related: [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572)

Comment: That's CommonJS syntax, not ES6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your requires are in NodeJS/io.js syntax, module in ES6 syntax looks like this:

```
import "./config/auth";
```

Or if you want to load something from it:

```
import authenticate from "./config/auth";
```

You can't load whole directories at once, but in Node/io.js you can create a module and then load that.

Note that as a workaround you can load a single file that in turn loads multiple files and returns their results. There is also work in progress on an asynchronous loader but that changes so often it's hard to keep track so I wouldn't rely on it just yet.

Comment: Maybe a loader that supported something like `import "./config/*"` wouldn't be a bad idea

Comment: @Bergi it's pretty easy to do it asynchronously using SystemJS (fs.readdirAsync .map load) - the problem is SystemJS is undergoing changes and it's also async (unlike what OP is doing).

Answer (score 3):

I personally use a package called [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir). This should work for you:

```
import requireDir from 'require-dir';
requireDir('./config');
```

Comment: a meta-require? require something to require something... lol

Comment: @igorsantos07 Welcome to JS :)

Comment: This is not a good idea as it assumes that modules are files in a directory at runtime, which is not the case in many build systems. If you do this, your code can break as soon as you try to port it to another build system.