# ES6 import module as an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using [this GULP plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-modules) which converts HTML files into ES6 exports so I could load them on the browser in my MVC (using [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) bundler).

Basically I have page controllers which are exported as modules.

Then, in my main JS file, I just import all the page controllers, once by one, like so (simplified):

```
import * as page__home from './pages/page1';
import * as page__home from './pages/page2';
...
```

Since this is an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), I would think it would be easier to somehow import all the page controllers into some object, so then when a controller is to be called, I could check if that name exist in that object which holds all the imported controllers, or something like that.

Or maybe there is a way to check if a module was imported somehow?
Is there any smarter way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: This reminds me of [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572), but I'm not sure whether it's a duplicate or just an XY problem.

Comment: @Bergi - I know how to import all files from a directory, that's not that, I mean, lets say somewhere in the code I expect some module to be available, how can I check that it was imported? lets say the module name is dynamic. so it's `"page__" + someName`

Comment: If the module name is really dynamic, you will need to use dynamic imports and dynamic module loading. If the imported modules are static, as your usage of the `import` syntax implies, there should be no reason to check that a module is available - all imported modules are available by definition (and when not, the complete module would fail).

Comment: I think I got it actually, I will combine all the controllers files using gulp, then import that one file, and it will all be under that namespace, like so `import * as pages from './pages/bundle';` then I could check `if( pages["xxx"] )...`

Comment: Yes, that would've been my suggestion as well - you actually want a single static import, and export a collection of your files (either as an object or just as multiple named exports).

Answer (score 2):

As noted above:

> I think I got it actually, I will combine all the controllers files using gulp, then import that one file, and it will all be under that namespace, like so import * as pages from './pages/bundle'; then I could check if( pages["xxx"] )

Comment: @vsync Thanks for asking. For context, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170641/unanswered-questions-with-just-comments