# How to Import and Export dynamically in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react component directory, I setted index.js here.

```
import App from './App';
import Main from './Main/Main';
import Best from './Main/Best';
import Club from './Main/Club';
import Post from './Main/Post';

import Sidebar from './Sidebar/Sidebar';

export { App, Main, Best, Club, Post, Sidebar };
```

Usage in other js,

```
import {
    App,
    Main,
    Best,
    Club,
    Post,
    Sidebar
} from '../scripts/Containers/index';
```

But whenever I make component like that, should I have to write import / export statements index.js there?
Is there any magical way?

Please help me to solve out this problem!

#### Update (with @Bergi)

I modifed like this, and it works well.

```
export { default as App } from './App';

export { default as Header } from './Header/Header';

export { default as Main } from './Main/Main';
export { default as Best } from './Main/Best';
export { default as Club } from './Main/Club';
export { default as Post } from './Main/Post';

export { default as Sidebar } from './Sidebar/Sidebar';
```

But this didn't work

```
export * from './App';

export * from './Header/Header';

export * from './Main/Main';
export * from './Main/Best';
export * from './Main/Club';
export * from './Main/Post';

export * from './Sidebar/Sidebar';
```

In order to works with above code, I changed this in component

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

    }
}
```

to

```
export class Header extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);

    }
}
```

I deleted `export default` module exports! And works second export way works(not first one)

Thanks @Bergi :)

But I think that dynamically import / export won't be able to use.

Maybe this is best way I think.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572) to me. Or are you looking for a way to dynamically generate such an `index.js` file?

Comment: You can avoid repeating each module's name using `export … from …;`

Comment: @Bergi In above my post, example code just say 6 components. But for example, If there were many folders and files in react component directory, I have to declare many import ... from ...;. It's so repetitive I think

Comment: Why do you have to `import` all of them in your other.js at all?

Comment: @Bergi Actually, I want to use each component with router(react-router). Because I'm implementing universal react, so I decided to seperate route module. I want to use that components in the route.

Comment: And to import subordinative components in another component.

Comment: You should use export default and then you will be able to import all props from this module like `import { someprops } from 'file'`