# import * doesn't load the object in es6

Tags: babeljs, ecmascript-6

i18n directory with index.js and the localization files: es.js, it.js and en.js.

index.js content:

```
export { default as es } from './es'
export { default as it } from './it'
export { default as en } from './en'
```

en.js content file (similar to es.js and it.js):

```
/*eslint-disable max-len,quotes*/
export default {
  "about.h1": "This is the title from the about page",
  ...
}
```

I try to load localization messages:

```
import * as i18n from 'i18n'
...
const intlData = {
  locale: 'en',
  messages: i18n['en']
}
```

However messages variable is undefined.

When I checked the console log with:

```
window.console.log(i18n)
```

I get undefined:

```
Object {__esMOdule: true}
 es:undefined
 get es: function get()
 it: undefined
 get it: function get()
 en: undefined
 get en: function get()
 __proto__: Object
```

Where I should get something like:

```
Object {__esMOdule: true}
 es: Object
 it: Object
 en: Object
 __proto__: Object
```

Comment: You can't load a directory in ES6, you have to import on a file-by-file basis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory)

Comment: Which transpiler are you using? That's more of an issue with the transpiler, not with ES6 itself.

Comment: I'm using a starter kit: https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Comment: Transpiler is babel 6

Comment: This way is really convinience so I just upload the file and the new language is ready for the app, without touching more code.  Similar code in https://github.com/emmenko/redux-react-router-async-example but I don't get it running in my environment!

Comment: This works for me running under babel-node.