# Meteor import all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having an issue while trying to import all files in one of my directories.

This works:

```
import '../pages/guidance/target_access_client_relationships.js';
```

While this doesn't:

```
import '../pages/guidance';
```

What am I doing wrong? I am planning to have quite a lot of files in 'guidance' and I'd rather not have to import every single file individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is to use a `index.js` and import all the file inside it.

EX:

```
dir A index.js

import './fileA.js'
import './fileB.js'

dir B  index.js

import './fileA.js'
import './fileB.js'
```

and finally you can make a parent dir and import both

```
parent dir index.js

import './dirB'
import './dirA'
```

Comment: Thank you! I will go with that

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible I don't think, but what you can do is this...

Create in the directory a index.js file which imports everything from the directory and exports it.

[import modules from files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory) has a similar answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the exports. I'll go with Emanuel Quimper's way, but I'll definitely save this for later