# Angular 2 unable to resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been playing around for a solid hour or two trying to get my app to work but I can't get a simple service injection to work anymore.

I have a core module which has the `GlobalsService` provided:

`core.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CoreComponent,

    SiteHeaderComponent,

    // Pages
    DocumentationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'documentation', component: DocumentationComponent},
      {path: '', component: CoreComponent}
    ]),
    DocumentationModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    GlobalsService,
    RegexService,
    UtilsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [CoreComponent]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

But when I try to use it in `site-header.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalsService} from '../../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'site-header',
  templateUrl: './site-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-header.component.scss']
})
export class SiteHeaderComponent {

  ns: string;

  constructor(private globals: GlobalsService) {
    this.ns = globals.ns;
  }
}
```

`globals.service.ts`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class GlobalsService {

   // App namespacer
   ns: string = 'test';
}
```

It just tells me that it can't resolve the parameter for the `GlobalsService` although it can find the service because if I change the import of it from `../../shared` it throws an error saying it can't find it, so that's not where the issue seems to be.

**EDIT:**

I have a `shared` folder which contains directives, pipes, services and shared modules. Inside it I use an `index.ts` file to export everything, hence why the path is only `../../shared` and not `../../shared/services/globals.service.ts`.

See image:

[image: shared folder]

`shared/services/index.ts`:

```
export * from './globals/globals.service';
export * from './regex/regex.service';
export * from './utils/utils.service';
```

`shared/index.ts`:

```
export * from './directives';
export * from './modules';
export * from './pipes';
export * from './services';
```

Can someone figure out what on earth I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you provide your GlobalService class too?

Comment: May be you have forgotten to add @Injectable into it?

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan Nope. I've had it working before but then I must've changed something which completely broke it.

Comment: There was an issue with barrel imports.. Are you using `2.1.0`?

Comment: @Sasxa I'm using the Angular CLI. Unsure which version it is.

Comment: Check `package.json`. I had similar issue, Try importing directly, like @PankajParkar suggested. If that fixes your issue, change all `2.0.0` to `2.1.0` (`3.1.0` for router) in package.json and run `npm upgrade`. You should be able to use index.ts for exports then...

Comment: @Chrillewoodz have you tried to stop server and run ng serve one more time?

Comment: @Sasxa Didn't appear to solve anything, I tried Pankaj's answer and it appears to work, but I don't understand why my barrels just suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan Yes multiple times but without luck.

Comment: I have not any idea. in core.module.ts you also take services from same ../../shared source?

Comment: @GevorgNarimanyan I do, adding `/services` after seems to work but I still can't figure out why doing just `/shared` stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have to put file name from share folder

```
import {GlobalsService} from '../../shared/global.service';
```

instead

```
import {GlobalsService} from '../../shared';
```

Comment: But I use an `index.ts` file in the shared folder which exports everything from within it

Comment: @Chrillewoodz why `index.ts`? where you did that?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31402500/2435473) inside your index.ts

Comment: This answer worked, but it makes no sense that the barrels just stops working all of a sudden. I will try the linked answer.

Comment: Doing `../../shared/services` seems to work for now, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz but that thing seems to work, could you add bug in github. so that angular team could look into this issue?

Comment: I will try to yes.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz from what I have been able to read from different issues, I think it may be a problem with re-exporting in barrels. For instance, the services barrel exports all the services, then shared barrel tries to export all the services from the services barrel.

Comment: @peeskillet That would make sense ye, but what doesn't make sense is that it once worked.. Did you find out if they're gonna fix this?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I think it's a problem with webpack and not angular.