# react compile error, Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error in my browser

```
Error in ./src/App.js
Module not found: ./components/todo in C:\Users\James\Desktop\react\src
```

This is what I got in my editor

```
import {TodoForm, TodoList} from './components/todo'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxPwr.jpg

I even tried `import {TodoForm, TodoList} from './components/todo/'` I wonder what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Imports work on a per module basis for most loaders/bundlers. In other words, you'll need to import the form and list by doing the following:

```js
import { TodoForm } from './components/todo/TodoForm'
import { TodoList } from './components/todo/TodoList'
```

As a side note, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export to make sure that you're exporting the components correctly. The curly braces around your import works for a named export as opposed to a default export.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://egghead.io/lessons/react-update-react-application-state-from-form-input, at minutes 0:16, you can see the author did not use multiple import.

Comment: What setup is the author using? Is here or she using webpack or browserify?

Comment: As others have mentioned, this typically requires an `index.js` script or regex import that exports all of the required dependencies. Most bundlers support this, and it looks like `create-react-app` has a transitive dependency on webpack.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is that when you do

```
import {TodoForm, TodoList} from './components/todo'
```

What happends is that your compiler will by default search the components `TodoForm` and `TodoList` from the `index.js` file since you have not mentioned explicitly which files to point to

So if in index.js you add something like

```
export * from './components/todo/TodoForm';
export * from './components/todo/TodoList';
```

Your approach will work.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the solution. Let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

In order to just import all files from the directory you must have an index.js file that exports everything from the directory

Which in your case the index.js file would look like this

```
Export * from 'TodoForm'
Export * from 'TodoList'
```

Note if the export statement doesn't work see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory) to fix the import / export statement

Answer (score 0):

Do you think, when you wrote `import {TodoForm, TodoList} from './components/todo'`, in `TodoForm` should be value than you exported from file `TodoForm.js`, and similarly with `TodoList`? It's don't works.
You should do import from some file. When you wrote `from './components/todo'` you tried doing import from `todo` directory. I guess, in egghead video that import works, because, they have `index.js` file in `todo` directory. And in this file they do export for every component separately. Try to add `index.js` file in `todo` directory with the following contents:

```
export * from './TodoForm.js';
export * from './TodoList.js';
```

it's will work.