# Simplify React Components Import

Tags: reactjs

I try to simplify my Components import, from:

```
import Component1 from './components/Component1'
import Component2 from './components/Component2'
```

To something like that:

```
import {Component1, Component2} from './components/'
```

I have tried to create an index.js file into components directory (following this post [import modules from files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory)):

```
export * from 'Component1';
export * from 'Component2';
```

But I still have a "Module not found" error.
Any clue ?

Thanks,
Orb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dot to indicate it is a local file, not an npm-published module. Change your exports line like so

```
export * from './Component1';
```

**UPD**
To resolve next issue with named import you need to give a name to default export from `Component1.js` file

```
export Component1 from './Component1';
```

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402500/351705)

Comment: Thanks.
I still have an error actually but not the same.
`'./components/' does not contain an export named 'Component1'.`

Comment: @Orboo It's because your `Component1.js` exports component as default. You need `export Component1 from './Component1` Follow this anwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402500/351705

Comment: `export {default as Component1} from './Component1'` works well (thx) but
`export Component1 from './Component1';` generate a syntax error.

Comment: It depends on your babel config. Compare [es2015,stage-0](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=export%20Component1%20from%20'.%2FComponent1'%3B) and [es2015](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=export%20Component1%20from%20'.%2FComponent1'%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path is correct?
Try to specify the absolute path like:

import Component1 from '/home/your_username/components/Component1'
import Component2 from '/home/your_username/components/Component2'

You can see the correct path of your directory from terminal with the command "pwd".

Be sure to have the access to the directory and file.
You can try to run the program as root.

Answer (score 0):

While exporting components from your Component1 and Component2 instead of *, you should export it as objects -

```
//In Component1.js(x)
export { Component1 };
```

and

```
//In Component2.js(x)
export { Component2 };
```

With this you should be able to import like:

```
import { Component1 } from '...';
import { Component2 } from '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I do the same thing with my imports and it's a lot nicer when they are being exported from the same file. Here's an example of how I achieve this:

components/index.js

```
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';

module.exports = {
    Component1,
    Component2
};
```

Then to import them

```
import { Component1, Component2 } from './components';
```

If you are using Webpack, check out [webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to get rid of your relative paths.

Example using Webpack resolve

```
//Will work at any nested level
import { Component1, Component2 } from 'components';
```

And just for clarification, `Component1` and `Component2` should be using a default export

```
export default class Component1 extends React.Component {...}
```

or

```
var Component1 = createReactClass({...});
module.exports = Component1;
```