# Export all from folder

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of folders with an index.js file that consist of many lines of:

```
export * from './filename'
```

And because I want to do this for every single file in the folder I was wondering if there is a way to just have one line that just exports everything in the whole folder instead of having to do one line for each file.

Some people think the question has been answered elsewhere, but no the answer given elsewhere is to do what I am doing which is to name every file in the index. What I want is a way to say 'my index exports * from every .js file in this folder'

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  You have "a lot" of identically named files in the same folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import modules from files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory)

Comment: Yep, your desire is right. Makes sense to have a regex as `from` argument. But it defies ES6 standards. Please see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20392).

Comment: @MattMorgan No I have a lot of folders with index files that I use to export all the functions and constants that are being exported in the files contained within the folder.

I'll edit the post for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer is no. Unfortunately. Reason is that you are getting a module or parts of one with the import command and every file is a module.

Sorry.

Comment: This does not answer the question, you could add a comment for that

Comment: Why @ashik? He asked if it could be done. I say no it cannot. Does answer his question as well as explains why. Dont down vote.

Comment: ashik, this IS an answer to the question. Whether you like it or not is a complete different thing. JGoodgive, ashik has the right to downvote an answer if he does not think it is right or accurate.

Comment: But there are ways, such as creating a script that automates populating an index file with exports, which does allow exactly that.