# React Importing a component folder

Tags: reactjs, import, components

I currently have my project folder as such

```
app
 - node_modules
 - public
 - src
  - Assets
  - Components
    - profiles
    - homepage
 - gulpfile
```

In my homepage component, I am trying to import the whole directory of profiles into an object like this (dynamically load each component as needed, but not all components will be loaded)

```
import Comps from '../profiles/';
```

also

```
import * as Comps from '../profiles/;
```

but I get an error in the compiler saying Module not found: Can't resolve '../profile.

I want to make it clear that profiles is a folder with components, and I want to select all components to call dynamically in my app.js file.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please expand/elaborate your file structure. What is "profiles" and what is "profile"?

Comment: oh I apologize, I changed part of the code and recopied it, that was just a mistake on my part. @5ar

Comment: If you are trying to import a folder (correct me if this is not the case), this might be something that interests you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory

Comment: Wow thank you!! this is exactly what I was looking for, just didn't word it correctly

Comment: No problem, some mod should soon get around marking this as a duplicate. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have several components in one js file, if so - you could do something like this:

Profiles.js:

```
import React from 'react';


export const ViewA = () => {
  return( <div>A VIEW</div>)
};
export const ViewB = () => {
  return( <div>B VIEW</div>)
};
export const ViewC = () => {
  return( <div>C VIEW</div>)
};
export const ViewD = () => {
  return( <div>D VIEW</div>)
};
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import * as Profiles from './Profiles';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Profiles.ViewA/>
        <Profiles.ViewB/>
        <Profiles.ViewC/>
      </div>
      )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I do not, I am rendering a paragraph to test it.so I have one component called user and rendering a <p> and at the bottom, I have export default user

Comment: did you try './profiles' vs '../profile' - they are in the same directory right?

Comment: Under components folder, there is a homepage rendering homepage components. If clicked a link to another page for a user/profile, it should go up one directory into components and into users and there will be multiple components there, but I want all to be readily available to be called, not necessarily calling the components