# ReactJS Route loading component within table not new page

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes

I am sorry first and foremost, I am a noobie trying to learn reactjs for a project at school. I am currently generating a table row with data passed through an array as such (dynamically through sockets)

NOTE: I am using bitcoin component as a measure of debugging only, I will eventually include this solution [import modules from files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
                {
                  coins.map((coin,i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                      <td className="coin_rank">{coin.rank}</td>
                      <td className="coin_link">
                        <img className = "coin_logo" src={require('./logos/' + coin.id + '.png')} alt = {coin.id}/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <Link to={'/coins/' + coin.id}>{coin.name}</Link>

                        <Route path={'/coins/' + coin.id} component={Bitcoin} />
                      </td>
                      <td className="coin_price"><NumberFormat value={coin.price_usd} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></td>
                      <td className="market_cap"><NumberFormat value={coin.market_cap_usd} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></td>
                      <td className="coin_supply"><strong>{coin.symbol}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<NumberFormat value={coin.available_supply} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} /></td>
                      <td className="coin_change">{coin.percent_change_24h}%</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
                }
```

It loads the component no problem, but it's loading in the same page 
[Example of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZtVc.png)

But I am trying to get it to open in a new page instead. I have my router components declared at the start and end of the render method. Is this something related to dynamic generating of my tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open the link in new page just set `target="_blank"` in the hyper links.

I don't have my dev machine at the moment, but we could pass every argument that an `anchor` tag accepts to `Link` component.

So `<Link target="_blank"` should work.

---

I have a feeling that you want the table to be replaced by the `BitCoin` Component rather that it being rendered in the same  table cell.

If that is the case, you need static routing. So the component which is rendered at the moment will be replaced by the component to which Link is pointing to.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/static-routing

Comment: This does not load the component and opens in a new tab. I am trying to load a component into a new page in the same tab

Comment: In an SPA there is only one page. So are you trying to route to a different component?

Comment: is a multi-page app possible? I thought it was (if SPA is single page app)

Comment: lol. I think I miss the whole picture here. Can you make a short version of all relevant Routes. Also, your intention is not clear from the picture.

Comment: All the components are the main home page and a bitcoin component. That's all I need to solve, and I can fix the rest of the issues through this one solution

Answer (score 0):

react-router is used to override the default browser behaviour when url changes and map it to your React app state so that you can render different components based on the url. If you are interested in more details, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History.

Opening a link in a new page is browser functionality. You don't need react-router and its Link component for it. Just render a simple html link with taget attribute:

`<a target="_blank" href={'/coins/' + coin.id}>{coin.name}</a>`

With this though, you'll probably hit another common pitfall with react-router. If you are just statically serving your assets, opening a non-root route in a new tab (or just refreshing it in an existing tab), will give you a 404 error from your server. If you run into this problem, this is again not react-router's thing, and you need to set up your web server to redirect any route to index.html (or whatever your html file is called).