# usage of JS plugins with webpack

Tags: jquery-plugins, webpack-encore

I am trying to reconfigure my Symfony 3 project to use webpack encore instead of normal asstets. I am a little stuck with this.

For one part of the application I developed some JS plugins which inherits from Kube (a CSS and JS Framework I am unsing). Here is an exmaple:

```
(function (Kube) {
Kube.Assignment = function (element, options) {

    this.namespace = 'assignment';
    this.defaults = {
        //...
    };

    Kube.apply(this, arguments);

    this.start();
};

Kube.Assignment.prototype = {

    start: function () {
        //...
    }
};

Kube.Assignment.inherits(Kube.Distribution);

Kube.Plugin.create('Assignment');
Kube.Plugin.autoload('Assignment');

}(Kube));
```

Unfortunatly Kube is not recognized.

The module 'imperavi-kube' is installed via yarn and is imported via

```
let Kube = require('imperavi-kube');
```

I am getting the following error: `TypeError: Kube.Assignment.inherits is not a function`

Propably this is not a issue of the Kube Framework but somthing about handeling JS plugins with webpack.

Inside the Kube module there is a class 'Kube' defined with a prototype. The Prototype ends with `window.Kube = Kube;`

Answer (score 2):

Try to import Kube like this:

```
import * as Kube from <your path> or <alias> or <module name>
```

I may be wrong, but as far as I remember sometimes it works a bit differently.

Comment: That worked! Is there a version of this line which uses the require method. As far as I can see I have to give the full relative path to the js file of kube (inside node_modules)?

Comment: Yes, or either you can add node_modules path to resolve/modules section in your webpack config (like this: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules') ), or use an alias.

Comment: Use `index.js` files to define exports so you don't have to specify the path to the file inside `node_modules` https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722646/9083959

Comment: Well, it is quite ambiguous to use such aproach when you're already using Webpack. Usually, if the module follows all naming conventions, it is enough to add  path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules') to webpack config and add modules by name. If the module doesn't follow all conventions, it might be necessary to add an alias. And anyway, it is much better then using a special file for that.