# how to run node / babel script directly in command line?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cli

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "99-nodetest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "babel-node --presets env app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "latest"
  }
}
```

The js script i want to run is app.js. I cannot run it directly using **node app.js** because app.js contains new language syntax.

Thus i have to run it through babel, using **npm start**, as per the start script defined above. No issues here.

My question is how to run the cmd directly in the command line, can it be done?
something similar to:

> npm run babel-node --presets env app.js

Comment: just FYI (and to make the link): the above question is related to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874360/how-does-mocha-babel-transpile-my-test-code-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --presets env app.js`

Comment: node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --presets env app.js . NB: its actually under babel-cli. if you change your answer, i wiil accept it

Comment: I ended up staying with Babel 6, instead of upgrading to Babel 7, just so I didn't have to deal with this regression.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2020+, with Babel v7 things have changed quite a bit ! You may need to look elsewhere rather than this accepted answer, which works with Babel 6 !

Answer (score 28):

You can execute npm package binaries with `npx`.

Because Babel 7 always resolves plugins and presets relative to local project folder, you will have to install `@babel/preset-env` locally into the project.

```sh
npm i -D @babel/preset-env
```

After that the `babel-node` can be run with `npx` without installation into the project:

```
npx -p @babel/core -p @babel/node babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env app.js
```

If you install `@babel/node` into the project, `npx` will prefer project-local version.

---

In case of Babel 6 the command below can be used:

```sh
npx babel-node --presets env app.js
```

Comment: In 2019:  `npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env app.js`

Comment: @ArneJenssen Thank you. Updated my answer. With Babel 7 it is actually much harder than it was with Babel 6, unfortunately

Comment: But How to give options for @babel/preset-env in the command.
Like "modules": false can be given in babel.config.json.
But how to give in command line?

Answer (score 14):

Great gugley mugleys!  This was way harder than it should have been.

See here for [docs](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation).  TLDR;

Babel > version 7.0 has to go in your `package.json` to run from command line.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/node 

npx babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env imports/test.js
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! "_By default, npx will check whether <command> exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute that."_ [npmjs.com/package/npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx)

Answer (score 8):

Install @babe/node globally-

```
npm i -g @babel/node
```

then babel-node command becomes available in your terminal. So, you can run -

```
babel-node --presets env app.js
```

Btw, it should be used in dev environment only, never recommended for production as it's unnecessarily heavy with high memory usage.

Comment: Best solution if you just want to run a quick test and not change the project.

Answer (score 2):

Babel node has a `bin` registered so an executable is generated on install inside the `node_modules/.bin` directory.

You may run it simply by typing.

```sh
node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets env app.js
```

Which accomplishes the same thing as the longer `node` or the alternate `npx` versions.

Answer (score 2):

in babel 7 you can run this:

`npx babel app.js`

Comment: Will `npx` (unlike Rodrigo's V6 answer above) pull all the required node_modules into cache? (Thus doing a lot more than on-the-fly-transpile+execution of local source code? Because I'd rather limit myself to that). — or is this not the case, when a local file (`app.js`) is given as parameter?

Answer (score -1):

You can run the `app.js` file from `node` by telling it about `babel-node` first:

`node ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node app.js`

with the following `.babelrc` file at the root project

`{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}`