# React, how to import all css files in a folder?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to make it easier on myself by importing all existing css files in a folder.

```
/styles
--element1.css
--element2.css
```

and exporting them as one big bad global stylesheet, which I can import in my index.js and worry about (for now)

```
import css from 'styled-jsx/css'
export default allStyles = css.global`*your css here*`
```

is how I know how to do it. 
But I want to write some regex fueled import loop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43508228/2138752