# How to import everything from one directory and export it

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, fs

Hi i have something like this:

[image]

I would like to import everything in directory (expect index.ts) to index.ts and then export it
I **don't want** to import everything like this:

```
import * as Network from './network';
import * as FirewallRule from './firewall-rule';

export { Network, FirewallRule };
```

Because it could be a lot of imports and export. Is it possible to do this automatically with fs npm module ?

Comment: see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help me so much, becuase i have to write extra export in index.ts. I'm looking for some kind of loader or hand-writing snippet of nodejs code that let me import and export everything. It could be done even with require statement.

Comment: OK, maybe this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337568/how-do-i-import-all-files-in-a-folder-as-an-module-and-export-all-as-an-object/55338300

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337568/how-do-i-import-all-files-in-a-folder-as-an-module-and-export-all-as-an-object/55338300 - duplicate