# Is there a way to import multiple exports under single variable?

Tags: reactjs

I am curious if there is more efficient and cleaner way to import `picture1, picture2, picture3` and later use them in the `img` tags as well? In reality I have many more pictures and it is adding extra lines of code that I would love to avoid.

I am using pictures from `picture.js` like that:

```
import {
  picture1,
  picture2,
  picture3,
} from './picture';

<img src={picture1} />
<img src={picture2} />
<img src={picture3} />
```

My `picture.js`

```
import picture1 from './picture_1.jpg';
import picture2 from './picture_2.jpg';
import picture3 from './picture_3.jpg';

export {
  picture1,
  picture1,
  picture1,
};
```

Ideally would want to have something like that:

```
import pictures from './picture';

repeat <img src=picture[index]>
```

Comment: Do you want to import *all* or just *some* pictures?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/5776910 the answer they had was "no, not really"

Comment: @str all the pictures was the goal :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import all pictures with *. and then use template string to access with index.

```
import * as pictures from './picture';

<img src={pictures[`picture${index}`]}
```