# Simplify import statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to question [Is it possible to import...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard) I've tried to simplify my import statements but debugger stops at `Attempted import error: 'TaskDropdown' is not exported from './oddments'.`

**oddements/index.js**

```
export * from './TaskBadge';
export * from './TaskDeadline';
export * from './TaskDropdown';
export * from './TaskInfoRow';
export * from './TaskStatusBadge';
```

**TaskDropdown.js**

```
export default TaskDropdown;
```

**somehwere else**

```
import { TaskStatusBadge, TaskInfoRow, TaskDropdown } from './oddments';
```

Possible walkaround is by using import/export at the same file.

```
import TaskBadge from './TaskBadge';
export {TaskBadge}
```

What could be wrong? Is the answer from mentioned thread correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write export as below

```
export { default as TaskDropdown } from './TaskDropdown';
```

Comment: Good point, ty. Use `export {TaskDropdown}` and `export * from './TaskDropdown';` works too.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple export from the same file can be done in two following ways:

```
1st Way:
 export function1 () {}
 export function2 () {}
 export function3 () {}
```

```
2nd Way:
export { function1, function2, function 3} from abc.js
```

Then you use import in the following two ways:

```
1st Way:
import { function 1, function2, function3 } from './abc'

//Then use it like:
function1();
```

```
2nd Way:
import * as abc from './abc'

//Then use it like:
abc.function1();
```