# typescript/javascript: How to do it that import all json from specific dir

Tags: javascript, typescript

Now in trouble that I don't know how to work.
I wanna to import all json from specific dir.

```js
import a from '../context/a.json'
import b from '../context/b.json'
import c from '../context/c.json'
```

↓

```
import {a, b, c} '../context/'   // but like..This code doesn't work.
```

Is there how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think this works at all, let alone with JSON?

Comment: I correct it a little words. I hope providing example can also work it. because the programming languages should be easier words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard)

Comment: How about creating a helper function to get all data from json files instead of import them?

Comment: @hoangdv: Actually, helper function as what you said is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an `index.js` file in your `context` directory which exports a, b, and c.

```
// context/index.js
export {default as a} from "./a.json"
export {default as b} from "./b.json"
export {default as c} from "./c.json"
```

Then when you need to import it, you could do

```
// some other js file
import { a, b, c} from "../context/index/"
```

Comment: The second form is proper, the first isn't.

Comment: Thank you for answer but your providing code doesn't work... I got an error msg 
[error TS1005: 'from' expected.] after compile within the upper code. and second code (export {default as a} from "./a.json") is no error msg. but some other js file provide console.log(a)//undefined

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for answer.
I make in order toas much as possible easier understand file.
After all, creating a helper function to get all json from specific dir.

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'
const readPath = './context/'

interface TypeList {
  [key: string]: string[] // adjusting require this in order to some json data type
}

export function DeclareEachJSON(): TypeList {
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(readPath).filter(file => file.match(/\.json$/))
  const typeList: TypeList = {}

  fileNames.forEach((fileName: string)=> {
    let typeName = fileName.match(/(^.*?)\.json/)
    if(typeName){
      typeList[typeName[1]] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(readPath + fileName, 'utf8').toString())
    }
  })
  return typeList
}
```