# Importing default value from each file in specified folder

Tags: javascript

Lets say in my project i have a folder `models` and i dont know how many js-files are within it? Is there way to import all default values from each file with sintax like this or something

```
import * as models from './models'
```

so variable models would have an object where keys are files' names and values are default values or i should import from each file separately?

Thank you

Comment: Are those files in ```models``` being used in every js file?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01, i cant get your question, sorry... just one file where i want to collect all default values from each file, which folder models contains

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard

Comment: @RanderGabriel, in negative way yes

Answer (score 1):

I assume you might have following structure:

```
models
|------> model1.js
|------> model2.js
```

So now Add another file called `index.js` as like as given below:

```
models
|------> model1.js
|------> model2.js
|------> index.js
```

And `index.js` file will be like:

```
import * as model1 from "./model1.js"
import * as model2 from "./model2.js"

export { model1, model2 };
```

Now you can call `models/index.js` file from anywhere as like as given below:

```
import * as models from "./models";

// models.model1
// models.model2
```

Hope it might solve your problem.

Comment: Now whats the point? The same way i can collect them in my file:

import * as model1 from "./model1.js";
import * as model2 from "./model2.js";

const models = { model1, model2 };