# Javascript ES6 import only some files from a folder

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, ecmascript-2016

Maybe I completely forgot how ES6 import/export works, but I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import { b } from 'folder';
```

and **not** load all of the other exported files from the folder index file.

This is what I currently have:

```
├── folder
│   ├── file1.js
│   ├── file2.js
│   ├── file3.js
│   └── index.js
├── test.js


//file1.js:
console.log("in file1");
export const a = 3 + 4;

//file2.js:
console.log("in file2");
export const b = 3 + 5;

//file3.js:
console.log("in file3");
export const c = 3 + 6;

//index.js:
export * from "./file1";
export * from "./file2";
export * from "./file3";

//test.js:
import { b } from "./folder";
console.log(`this is ${b}`);
```

The problem is that when doing this it loads the other two files (a and c) as well, shown by the output:

```
in file1
in file2
in file3
this is 8
```

How can I import various files from `folder` **without** having to use specific file import:

```
import { b } from "./folder/file2";
```

as I might have to import quite a lot of files from that folder, and I wish I could use import destructuring.

So instead of:

```
import { b } from "./folder/file2";
import { c } from "./folder/file3";
```

I want to be able to use:

```
import { b, c } from "./folder";
```

but without having to load the other files from the folder (a in this case).

Comment: Similar question here(You can make use of some of the workarounds mentioned in this thread) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

`How can I import various files from folder without having to use specific file import`, you can't. Exports are determined during runtime, which means that the `index.js` file needs to be evaluated in order to determine what should be exported.

However you can design your files in such a way that evaluating them doesn't run any business code.

For example:

```js
//file1.js:
export const Module1 = () => {
  console.log("in file1");
  return ({
    a: 3 + 4,
  });
}
```

```js
//test.js
import { Module1 } from "./folder";
const { a } = Module1();
```