# Unable to import directory in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My file layout is as follows:

```
// Folder structure:
//    |-src
//        |-util
//             |-index.js
//             |-PageScreen1.js
//             |-PageScreen2.js (and etc...)
//        |-PageScreen.js
//        |-index.js
```

I would like to import all of util into PageScreen. At the top of PageScreen.js I put

```
import * as All from ./util
```

but this results in a module not found error. Could I get some advice on how to solve this issue?

EDIT: I've added an index.js folder as suggested in one of the answers below. Everything works if I import/export the PageScreens like

```
import PageScreen1 from './PageScreen1';
import PageScreen2 from './PageScreen2';

export {PageScreen1, PageScreen2};
```

However I have many PageScreen.js files, so is there a way to quickly import/export all of them?

Comment: util is a folder not a file with modules. May be you should try:

import * as All1 from ./util/PageScreen1.js
import * as All2 from ./util/PageScreen2.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard)

Comment: @PeterB i added an index.js file inside of my util folder. There, I am able to follow the answer you sent me and manually import PageScreen1/2. However, if I have many PageScreens, I do not want to manually import / export all of them. Is there something like import * that I can use for index.js? From the answer you sent me it seems like its not possible but I hope there is an actual way to do what I want

Answer (score 1):

You need an `index.js` inside the `util` directory.

It should import everything from all the other files and then export them again.

Comment: Okay, I created an index.js file within my util directory. Inside of it I did import * as All from 'util', then did export default All. This does not seem correct as I'm unable to access All.PageScreen1 from the outer index.js. I'm quite inexperienced with ReactJS.

Comment: edit: I manually imported each individual file and exported them as export {PageScreen1, PageScreen2} but is there a way to just import all and export all from the index file? I have many pagescreens and do not want to manually type it all out

Answer (score 1):

To import every file you need to add one more slash. it should be ./util/ .
You are missing a slash
By default in your case react is importing util/index.js

```js
import * as All from './util/'
```

other ways (organized) can be as follows:
inside index.js you can export all files and then get them into outer space

```js
import PageScreen1 from './PageScreen1'
....

export default {PageScreen1,PageScreen2}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without manually importing into the index.js file? For example, is there something like import * from ./util that I can use inside the index.js file?

Comment: just add slash './util/'