# Import a folder of images

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I have a Svelte+Sapper project in which this works just fine:

```
import logotype from 'images/logo_vertical.svg';
```

[..]

```
<img src={logotype} alt="..." />
```

But is it possible to import an entire folder as such:

```
import logotypes from 'images/logotypes';
```

.. and use them like this:

```
<img src={logotypes.logo1} alt="..." />
```

or

```
<img src={logotypes['logo1.svg']} alt="..." />
```

I have tried importing like this but it does not work since it is then looking for a module rather than a set of images: `import logotypes from 'images/logotypes';`

> 'images/logotypes' is imported by ....svelte, but could not be
> resolved – treating it as an external dependency

And in runtime...

> Error: Cannot find module 'images/logotypes'

Comment: It's not possible to import a folder that way. You could create an intermediary module file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722646/1870780 as an alternative.

Comment: There is a babel-plugin called [import-all.macro](https://github.com/kentcdodds/import-all.macro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea Julio Malves, this is what I came up with (in file/images/logos/index.js):

```
import logo1 from './logo_1.svg'
import logo2 from './logo_2.svg'
import logo3 from './logo_3.svg'
import logo4 from './logo_4.svg'
import logo5 from './logo_5.svg'
import logo6 from './logo_6.svg'

export default {
    logo1,
    logo2,
    logo3,
    logo4,
    logo5,
    logo6,
}
```

And using it like;

```
import logos from 'images/logos'
```

[..]

```
<img src="{logos.logo1}" alt="[..] />
```

Comment: I think it's the best solution. This could be automatized by generating this code with a Node script (maybe going fancy, with a file watcher on the folder and all). This could also be automatized further with a bundler plugin, to detect that you are trying to import a folder, but this one doesn't seem like a good idea -- this would fragilise your build setup, and risk conflicts (with the index.js of the folder, and how can you tell that when you're trying to import a folder, that's for the images?). I think you should accept this answer.

Comment: If I would have hundreds of resources I probably would automate it but this works for now, thanks for confirming the solution, if no one comes up with anything better I´ll accept this as the best solution.