# React component map based on an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dynamically create an element based on passed ID:

```
const Icon: FC<IconPropsI> = ({iconId, ...rest}) => {
  const iconsMap: IconsMapT = {
    IconUser: IconUser,
    IconTime: IconTime,
    IconVideo: IconVideo
  }

  return createElement(iconsMap[iconId], rest)
}
```

*Value of each map property has corresponding **functional** component.*

I would like to avoid repeating myself. I have created a list of IDs instead. With the following array...

```
export const IconsIds: IconsIdsT = [ 'IconUser', 'IconTime', 'IconVideo', 'manymore...']
```

...how can I create the map dynamically inside the `Icon` component, so I don't have to write 200+ different icon IDs three times?

Answer (score 1):

In `iconsMap` you could also use property shorthand to not repeat yourself.

So instead of `const iconsMap = { IconUser: IconUser }` you should be able to do something like `const iconsMap = { IconUser, ...otherIcons }`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions

Alternatively, there's a `babel` plugin that can compose all exports from a certain folder to a single object, and then you can get values from this object.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43508228/8252978)

But please, be aware of potential issues - if you will pass wrong `iconId`, or if your bundler expects all imports being statically defined(AFAIK - at least `react-native` and `expo` expects that) - you might face issues with such an approach, and manual map typing might be more resilient solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kirill. Maybe I should have been more precise when asking. The subcomponents (like `IconUser`) are functional components as well as `Icon` is. They are not imported as svgs.

Comment: Basically, with the array I'm creating a type to prevent mistakes when choosing the right icon and with that array I want to create the map too. I may be wrong but I don't see how your answer could help me.