# convert module.exports[something] to es6 syntax

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I am migrating my code from commonJS to es6 as I have to upgrade my node version to 16+.

But, I got stuck here.

```
  module.exports[path.parse(file).name] = sequelize.import(dir+'/'+path.parse(file).name);
```

I need to convert it to es6 syntax. Tried to google it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can't, really. ES modules require statically named exports. Where does `file` come from?

Comment: @Bergi
Exactly what I feared. I can't export dynamically, can I ? :'( 
The file is coming recursively inside folder and subfolder. 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do? How is this code used?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to load some models from different folders into one.

Comment: btw [`sequelize.import` is deprecated](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html)

Comment: "*I am trying to load some models from different folders into one.*" - then just list them explicitly. Or have that module be automatically generated for you.

Comment: This is what I am facing right now. As it is deprecated, they are telling to use require instead of sequelize.import. 
But, how can I use require in es6? Is there any alternative to that? Would be a much help. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to list them explicitly. But as you said, sequelize.import is deprecated, and I am not able to use require in es6, Is there any alternative?

Comment: Have  a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572

Comment: Sure, thanks. Will look into it.