# How to import all modules i have into one ts file then export it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Im totally new in Ts so, i was wondering if I can import all classes i have into one ts file then export it from there, so whenever i want any class i can import it directly from this file

```
import Login from "./Login/login_page";
import MyAccount from "./AccountSettings/myAccount_page";
import Settings from "./AccountSettings/settings_page";
import DataProvider from "../utils/data-provider/data-provider";


export default { Login, MyAccount,Settings, DataProvider};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do it. But there can be atmost one default export in a file. So, you can have it or not, its optional.

So, for example :

```
import Login from "./Login/login_page";
import MyAccount from "./AccountSettings/myAccount_page";
import Settings from "./AccountSettings/settings_page";
import DataProvider from "../utils/data-provider/data-provider";

export default DataProvider; 

export { MyAccount,Settings, DataProvider} ;
```

or

```
import Login from "./Login/login_page";
import MyAccount from "./AccountSettings/myAccount_page";
import Settings from "./AccountSettings/settings_page";
import DataProvider from "../utils/data-provider/data-provider";


export {DataProvider, MyAccount,Settings, DataProvider} ;
```