# Modular structure in React and TypeScript library

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, package.json, rollup

I create one library with React, Typescript and rollup following this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-component-library-react-typescript/) , everything works fine, but now that I am adding more features in my project I want to be able to have modular exports (not sure if this is the correct name), something like we have in redux and other libraries, that you can import files from different sub folders like  **redux/store** or **redux/hooks** etc...

Asking ChatGPT it says that I have index.ts and export everything from the subfolders, and re export in index.ts from the root level, but in the end what happens is that I am able to import everything from my main module like this.

`import { component1, style1, hook1 } from 'my-library'`

But what I want to achieve is something like this.

```js
import { component1, componenet2 } from 'my-library'; 
import { style1, style2 } from 'my-library/styles';  
import { hook1, hook2 } from 'my-library/hooks';
```

I know this is possible because a lot of libraries do that, but I have no idea in how to achieve that.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard)

Not sure that this is the only/best way to do this - others may have better solutions.

I haven't done this before. It probably isn't necessary or standard unless your project is very big. There may be some performance penalties for importing everything in every file (it might also increase the chance of circular dependencies) though I am no Js expert.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I am looking for, I am able to do what is describe in the link you post, but I what I want is bit more complex.